# SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 not working on windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, rest, tls1.2

I have a windforms application which reads/write data to shopify using Shopify's restful API. Up until recently its been working fine.

A user let me know it wasnt working. After I got a copy of their database, and tried to communicate with Shopify in my dev environment, it didnt work for me either.

After some digging around, I found it was the SecurityProtocolType I was using. I changed it from Tls to Tls12, and it started working great in my dev environment. Hooray.

But when I made a new installer, installed it on a windows 10 machine, and connected to the same database I used in my dev environment, it didnt work.

I tested it again on a windows 7 virtual machine (again, connected to same database), it worked!

I'm now starting to suspect it is a windows 10 vs windows 7 thing (My dev machine is windows 7).

A few extra details:

The dotnet version of the winforms app is 4.5.

The error I'm getting on the win 10 machine is: "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."

Can anyone offer any tips on where to go from here? Is there any reason why windows 10 wont run Tls12 in a .net 4.5 winforms application?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "check dll vesion". The Tls12 bit is part of System.Net, so I'm not installing this part - It should already be there (as part of dotnet).

And what do you mean by "Change your dll version"? the dotnet version?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up upgrading my whole solution from dotnet 4.5 to dotnet 4.6.1. Works fine in windows 10 now.

Not sure why dotnet 4.5 was not playing nicely with Tls12 on windows 10, but at least I have a solution.